# Different Session Cookie for Different Paths

Tags: php, cookies, session-storage

I need to store separate cookies for individual directories on my site.  I have read several articles on how this can be accomplished, but I have not been able to get any of the solutions to work for me.  I am executing one of these lines on each page (`COOKIE_PATH = '/city_dir/'`):

```
session_set_cookie_params($lifetimeSeconds, COOKIE_PATH);
```

or

```
session_save_path(COOKIE_PATH);
```

Followed by:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])){ 
    $data = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']; 
    $timeout = time() + $lifetimeSeconds; 
    session_start();
    setcookie('PHPSESSID', $data,  $timeout); 
}
else {
    session_start();
}
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

The first line (`session_set_cookie_params`) sounded like the correct solution, but when I use that line, no cookies show up at all in the Chrome web developer tool listing, and I am unable to log in to the site.

The second line doesn't sound like the correct solution (seems I should be dealing with the cookie path, not the save path), but it comes closer.  The first time a page loads, I see a cookie for path "/".  If I refresh the page, that cookie remains, and a cookie is listed for the path `COOKIE_PATH`.  Unfortunately, I am still unable to log in.  I searched and tried many variations all weekend, but could not get anything to work.  What am I missing?  I am using PHP Version 5.3.18.

Comment: [session_save_path()](http://php.net/session_save_path) has nothing to do with cookies; it sets the server directory where stuff gets stored. In fact, I can't understand the relevance of your code after `session_set_cookie_params()`. The problem is most likely that: 1) `COOKIE_PATH` contains an invalid path (you don't say it clearly but you suggest you're omitting the leading slash) 2) You are also using sessions in your site root

Comment: `session_set_cookie_params` should work. I have a working implementation that does exactly what you describe.

Double check your assumptions. Is the session started? Do you see the session being created on the server? Do you get a session cookie?

Comment: Sometimes browsers can show weird behavior if you have a session cookie for a parent path; they will send the wrong cookie. Clear your cookies to make sure you're not running into this issue.

Comment: @Frits van Campen `session_set_cookie_params` is now working, but only after I added `session_name($cookieName)` before calling it.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to store separate cookies for individual directories on my site

Are you really *REALLY* sure this is the only way to solve the problem? You should only even attempt this if someone is holding your family hostage.

If the lives of your loved ones is under threat, then use a different session name for the different sessions. You could still associate the resulting cookies with different paths - but this is coincidental.

You are confusing the cookie path and the session handler path in your question.

Your code as it stands binds an existing session (you don't know where it came from - in most cases, it is the the path the browser is already on) and rebind the existing session. It is just possible that this is actually what you intend - but is still extremely dangerous. Assuming that you understand and manage the risk of fixation, then using differnt session names is still a better solution.

Perhaps if you told us *why* you need to this, we might be able to come up with more sensible advice on how to solve the problem.

Comment: With this application, one person is working with multiple cities (each city needs its own set of session data) simultaneously. They have one city open in each of a number of tabs, and manage details of each city throughout the work day. Let me know if that is still not clear.

Comment: I know of a valid use-case but yours does not seem like one. Add the city to the request in a different manner, like the request-url. This also makes it really obvious to the user what city he is working on.

Comment: @Frits van Campen: One requirement that makes me believe that I need a separate session for each city is that my client now wants to track when each user logs in and out of each city. In addition, the same user could have different permissions for different cities.

Answer (score 0):

[`session_save_path()`](https://www.php.net/function.session-save-path) is used to define where to store cookies on the server, and I'm not sure this is what you need.

The documentation of [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) lists another `path` param which may be useful if your "path" is really the portion of the URL after the port used to access the script.

I would not play with `PHPSESSID` because it's used to track users sessions, and it's quite unusual to have different sessions on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a session name has given me the functionality I was looking for (lightly tested):

```
session_name($cookieName);
session_set_cookie_params($lifetimeSeconds, $cookiePath);
```

With this code, there is no PHPSESSID cookie, just the named cookie.

The issue has also been raised whether this is the appropriate approach, and that issue is still open.  After reading up on session fixation, it sounds like that risk was with the code I had included after the cookie setting.  That code was actually meant to address a different issue, I only included it because I thought it may have an impact on the cookie/session issue presented in the original question.

@Frits van Campen: One requirement that makes me believe that I need a separate session for each city is that my client now wants to track when each user logs in and out of each city.  In addition, the same user could have different permissions for different cities.

So, if this is a bad approach, why is it bad (security, maintainability, etc)?  What are other options (I can only come up with moving to subdomains).

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be making this more difficult than it has to be. A site can set MANY cookies in a client's browser, but they don't follow directory structures.

What you want to do is something like:

```
setcookie('Akron',$data_about_akron,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day
setcookie('Boston',$data_about_boston,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day
```

and then retrieve it with:

```
$data_about_akron = $_COOKIE['Akron'];
```

Comment: @FritsvanCampen read the question before you stomp around downvoting everyone's answers. He's misusing session vars in an attempt to set different cookies. His FIRST SENTENCE is: "I need to store separate cookies for individual directories on my site. "  I do however agree that messing with PHPSESSID cookie is bad...

Comment: I think that's open for interpretation (sessions use a cookie after all). Since he's talking about a login he probably wants a session since cookies are not safe. There other problems with your answer too. `setcookie` does have a `$path` parameter. I would ask for clarification about what is in `$data_about_akron` before posting an answer.

Comment: @Digital Chris I need separate cookies to store a session id for each user's login for each city.  Also, the directory structure is relevant in that when a user is in a specific city's directory, I want to use a cookie (i.e., session id) that corresponds with that city (e.g., when on site.com/akron, get the cookie named "akron"--if I change the url to site.com/boston, they would need to login to boston, at which time a new "boston" session and cookie would be created that would include their permissions for boston).